# Mysql distinct sum, group by

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
id  user_id   type   value

1   1         type1     2
2   2         type1     1
3   1         type2     5
4   1         type1     2
```

I want output like this:

```
  user_id   type1   type2
    1         4     5
    2         1     0
```

please help

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted anything? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Are the values of the type column fixed to type1 and type2, or that can be various?

Comment: type column is fixed

Comment: Then I think either solutions below would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    sum( if( type = 'type1', value, 0 ) ) AS type1,  
    sum( if( type = 'type2', value, 0 ) ) AS type2
FROM 
    table_name 
GROUP BY 
    user_id;
```

Comment: i want the some of value

Comment: What do you mean by 'some of value'?

Comment: sorry, typo.
I want sum of the value column,
ok fine i got it.

Comment: Oh. I missed the `value` column. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is what you are searching for:

```
select 
   user_id,
   (select sum(value) from <yourtablename> sub1 where type = 'type1' where sub1.user_id = baseTable.user_id) as type1,
   (select sum(value) from <yourtablename> sub2 where type = 'type2' where sub2.user_id = baseTable.user_id) as type2,
from
   <yourtablename> baseTable
```